# Generic should be output class in typescript in factory method

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

I would like to pass a generic so i can pre-type my returned class.

```js
public createVehicle<O extends AbstractVehicle>(
  type: string
): O {
  switch (type) {
    case "Car":
      return new Car(param1, param2);
    case OfferType.Sale:
      return new Bike(param3, param4)    
    default:
      throw new Error("Vehicle type not supported");
  }
}
```

however this gives me:

```
Type 'Car' is not assignable to type 'O'.
  'Car' is assignable to the constraint of type 'O', but 'O' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'AbstractVehicle'
```

which i kind of understand as it can be something like `AbstractVehicle & {}` but shouldn't this just be an easy thing to do?

Tried for hours without solution, it keeps throwing that error. any suggestions to keep this simple and readable?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to expect a concrete type from a factory. The whole idea of the factory is that it will give you back something that fulfils an interface, not that you'd have one thing to call and you'd expect *exactly* one of several possible implementations. If that was the case, then your code would be exceptionally brittle, as you'd have to expect that `myFactory(something)` returns a specific type which means that you cannot change that implementation to produce a different thing. The signature here should just be `createVehicle(type: string): AbstractVehicle`

Comment: @Maxim Can you show more details about `AbstractVehicle`, `Car`, `Bike` and so on please?

Answer (score 0):

Your function is not generic over its return type. You should just write

```
createVehicle(type: string): Car | Bike
```

or

```
createVehicle(type: string): AbstractVehicle
```

and call it as `createVehicle("Car") as Car` not `createVehicle<Car>("Car")`.

If anything, your function is generic over its argument type, and you can infer the return type from that:

```
public createVehicle<T extends "Car" | "Bike">(type: T): T extends "Car" ? Car : T extends "Bike" ? Bike : never
```

This will infer the correct result type for the call `createVehicle("Car")` (i.e. `typeof createVehicle<"Car">("Car")` = `Car`), but for `createVehicle(unknownType)` it will still infer the union.

Comment: but i want it to automatically detect it cause the child type sometimes has different methods. using `as` is a possibility but was wondering whether it can not be automatic

Comment: @Maxim Then use the `createVehicle<T extends "Car" | "Bike">(type: T): …` approach, which will automatically detect (infer) the generic parameter and therefore the return type when you call it with a constant. But really, if you depend on the instance to have some specific methods, why do you use `createVehicle` at all and not just `new Car` (or `new Bike`) directly?